# Setting 'params filter' in url only when filter is set to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I send a request I get an error from the server 500. `type20`,       `type30 is undefined`. `type30` will be supplemented with value in the future. How to set `'filter [status]': [type10, type20, type30]`, so that `type20` or `type30` will only appear when it has a completed value.

```
 this.setState({
  type10: 10,
  type20: '',
  type30: ''
})

handle = () => {
  {type10, type20, type30} = this.state;
  const params = {
    expand: 'project,labels',
    'filter[status]': [type10, type20, type30],
  }

  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/todos`,
    method: "GET",
    params
  })
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }) 
}
```

Comment: You gotta have to look into your server. What is the error it returns?

Comment: `will only appear when it has a completed value` what do you mean by `completed value` ?

Comment: You will need to provide us some more information to try to understand your problem. 500 means internal server error, maybe you should start checking your backend

Comment: @Vencovsky `type20` will be have value 20, `type30` will be have value 30

Comment: @Drusto If I have `'filter[status]': [type10]` everything is ok, because `type10` has value. `type20`, `type30` should have value 20, 30. These values will be added later

Comment: @Yanis f I have 'filter[status]': [type10] everything is ok, because type10 has value. type20, type30 should have value 20, 30. These values will be added later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access state like that either you have to destructure state or use it directly from the state

```js
 this.setState({
  type10: 10,
  type20: '',
  type30: ''
})

handle = () => {
  const params = {
    expand: 'project,labels',
    'filter[status]': [this.state.type10, this.state.type20, this.state.type30],
  }

  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/todos`,
    method: "GET",
    params
  })
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }) 
}
```

or

```js
 this.setState({
  type10: 10,
  type20: '',
  type30: ''
})

handle = () => {

  const {type10, type20, type30} = this.state 
  const params = {
    expand: 'project,labels',
    'filter[status]': [type10, type20, type30],
  }

  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/todos`,
    method: "GET",
    params
  })
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }) 
}
```

things you have asked in the comment that means when you have some properties in your state then you will pass it but when doesn't in there you can't set if you set something undefined in your object this won't get pass through Axios object. 
Try this approach here you will send those data which are stored in state. You won't have to worry about which data you will send spread operator will do it for you

```js
this.setState({
  type10: 10,
  type20: '',
  type30: ''
})

handle = () => {


  const params = {
    expand: 'project,labels',
    'filter[status]': [...this.state],
  }

  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/todos`,
    method: "GET",
    params
  })
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }) 
}
```

Comment: I forgot add  const {type10, type20, type30} = this.state. But it isn't problem.  If I have 'filter[status]': [type10] everything is ok, because type10 has value. type20, type30 should have value 20, 30. These values will be added later

Comment: in that case, you can use spread operator. Let me add another section in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should destructure your state at the beginning of handle

```
handle = () => {
  const { type10, type20, type30 } = this.state; // Here

  const params = {
    expand: 'project,labels',
    'filter[status]': [type10, type20, type30],
  }

  axios({
    url: `/api/v1/todos`,
    method: "GET",
    params
  })
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }) 
}
```

Comment: you can also use state directly

Comment: @NicolasDuque I forgot add const {type10, type20, type30} = this.state. But it isn't problem. If I have 'filter[status]': [type10] everything is ok, because type10 has value. type20, type30 should have value 20, 30. These values will be added later